# To reopen a question by another guy. I don't think it is really opinion-based

Tags: support, reopen-closed

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59860684/reset-css-using-all-unset) question two days ago and posted my answer.

It seems now the question is closed as opinion based, but I personally consider it quite interesting and although the question is formulated in the opinion-based way, the person who asked it actually needs a list of pros/cons of each approach && differences between them, and I think this is about facts, not opinions.

Isn't it better to reopen it?

Comment: Are you sure the question isn't a (multi-)duplicate?

Comment: @VLAZ Well, it may be. But I personally don't see any dupes. I found it by Google and there wasn't any other similar results.

Comment: I'm not an expert there but at a glance it seems like something that might have been covered in other question(s).

Comment: Pros and cons **are** opinion based...what you think is a pro I might think is a con.

Comment: @Paulie_D Well, differences. What I really mean is that this question can be answered in not-opinion-based way.

Comment: Then perhaps you should edit the question to remove all the opinion based stuff but I'm pretty sure this will get closed as a multi-dupe.

Comment: I'd just change `Why should I use` to `Are there any advantages to using`, to make it clear that the question is about contrasting the approaches without looking for a (possibly opinion-based) judgement.

Comment: Why does it need to be reopened? Do you want more competition for upvotes on your answer? Because that's all reopening will accomplish; allow others to answer.

Comment: @jsv https://www.bing.com/search?q=css+why+reset gives decent amount of information  including https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578819/css-reset-what-exactly-does-it-do. If you feel that opinion-based close is wrong - duplicate seem to be perfectly fine... Indeed you can also argue that it should be downvoted to death for not showing research  (there are some explanations what "reset"/"normalize" CSS do as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset - so I strongly recommend you at least to add that research *before* spotlighting on meta)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Reopening will do more. It will make it harder to delete and it will signal it's a valid Question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Keeping a question closed to "protect" your answer on it seems like an abuse of the closure system. Not saying whether or not this particular question should be reopened, just that's a bad argument against it.

Comment: I agree that the question isn't opinion based, and is more asking about the difference between two options. I asked about this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/51802676) and the feedback was that there were too many differences for the question to be sufficiently narrowly scoped. IIRC I voted to close the question as "Needs Focus".

Comment: @JohnMontgomery The OP in this case doesn't have the privilege to interact with the closure system, so they could hardly abuse it. But I concede your point, perhaps I shouldn't have targeted their baser instincts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question isn't really opinion-based, despite the use of the word "should."  It's asking, basically, what a CSS reset does that the simple snippet in the question does not.  It can be (and was) answered in a non-opinion-based way by describing those differences, without rendering an opinion as to whether one *should* use one.  An opinion-based question might be something like "Should I use a CSS reset?", which can't really be answered objectively.

It is, however, possibly a duplicate of an existing question, possibly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11578819/208273) proposed in the comments.  I'm not an expert on the subject matter, so I'm not sure—this answer may tread some ground that's not explicitly covered in the duplicate target.

Comment: As someone who commented on that suggested duplicate nearly 9 years ago, no, they're two vastly different questions altogether.

Comment: "This question isn't really opinion-based" that seems like, your opinion man. :D